# Remove Table from HTML or XAML C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, html-table, flowdocument

I have used a HTML to XAML (FlowDocument) conversion script, the only problem is that I don't want tables to be displayed.

I would prefer using the HTML code for this example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

OK just for examples sake, that is the formatting of the table, as it is. I would like to replace the tags with something maybe like a `<p>` or `<br />` how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **very** simplistic terms:

```
string html = "...";
html = html.Replace("<table>","<p>");
html = html.Replace("<td>","");
html = html.Replace("</td>"," ");
html = html.Replace("<tr>","");

html = html.Replace("</tr>","<br/>");
html = html.Replace("</table>","</p>");
```

You'll get an extra space after your closed  in case you have more than one .  You can account for this through more thorough logic.

Comment: That actually ended up removing all the content from the table for some reason.

Comment: You are removing the html = ..., and setting it to your html right?

Comment: Yes that's right, it just gives me back no content at all weirdly enough

Comment: OK I gave it another try and it does work now, there was a problem with the conversion script not allowing <p> tags and it was returning nothing